# Python extension building with boost

Tags: c++, python, c, boost

I am fairly new to the boost c/c++ library. I downloaded boost library and build the library.

I created a very simple python library in c++ using boost interface (actually it is example code given in the documentation). I built it into a dll file. In the documentation it reads that this dll is exposed to python and they just show the import function in python and include the created library.
I don't understand how to expose that dll to python and load the library inside in tradition ('import') manner.
In case if you wanna look at the code then here it is:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

Please help I really want to build applications with c/c++ and python.
I simply want to use hello_ext as:

```
>>>import hello_ext
>>>print hello_ext.greet()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your compilation producing a dll file? Are you getting errors? What happens when you run `import hello_ext`?

Comment: Yes my compilation did produce a dll and when i do import hello_ext the interpreter raises ImportError: No module named hello_ext.

Answer (score 1):

> I built it into a dll file. In the documentation it reads that this dll is exposed to python and they just show the import function in python and include the created library. I don't understand how to expose that dll to python and load the library inside in tradition ('import') manner.

You need to put that shared library into [the module search path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). There are a few ways to achieve that.

One is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<directory-where-hello_ext-module-resides>")
import hello_ext
```

Your shared library should be called `hello_ext.dll`.

Comment: That shared library(Dll) is in python's DLLs folder. But I still tried and added that directory from interpreter but it still says that the module does not exist. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user1544053 What is the exact name of your DLL?

Comment: It is PythonDll.dll and it resides in "Python27/DLLs/PythonDll.dll".

Comment: @user1544053 rename your dll to `hello_ext.dll`. See http://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html#building-on-windows for more details.